Solution Of 2D Logarithmic PDE In Periodic Potential In Imaginary-Time Propagation Method
I am trying to solve Eq.no.(8) from https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.06804 and generate Fig. (3)-(4). The problem I am facing is that in imaginary time propagation method the solution is growing with time as a result the particle number does not remain constant, it is also growing. The solution I am getting does not match their results as well.
Here is my code for N=22 fig(3 a2)
boundary = 15; xl = yl = -boundary; xr = yr = boundary;
finalt = 10;
von[x_, y_] := -2 (Cos[\[Pi]/5 x]^2 + Cos[\[Pi]/5 y]^2);
svalue = 0;
seedwave[x_, y_, 
   t_] := (x^2 + y^2)^(svalue/2) Exp[
    I*svalue  ArcTan[x, y] - 0.07 (x^2 + y^2)] ;
pnumber = 
 Integrate[
  Abs[seedwave[x, y, 
    0]]^2, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}](*particle number check*)
sol = NDSolveValue[{-D[\[Psi][x, y, t], 
       t] == -0.5  Laplacian[\[Psi][x, y, t], {x, y}] + 
      Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^2  \[Psi][x, y, t]  Log[
        Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^2] + von[x, y] \[Psi][x, y, t], \[Psi][
      xl, y, t] == \[Psi][xr, y, t] == 
     0, \[Psi][x, yl, t] == \[Psi][x, yr, t] == 0, \[Psi][x, y, 0] == 
     seedwave[x, y, 0]}, \[Psi], {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr}, {t, 0, 
    finalt}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 40, "MaxPoints" -> 81, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}},
    MaxSteps -> 10^6];

Visualization
  {Table[DensityPlot[Abs[sol[x, y, t]]^2, {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr}, 
       PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t*1.}], 
       ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotPoints -> 100, 
       PlotLegends -> Automatic], {t, 2, 10, 2}], 
     Plot[{Abs[sol[x, 0, 2]]^2, von[x, 0]}, {x, xl, xr}, PlotRange -> All,
       PlotLegends -> {"sol", "pot"}]}

Particle no check
Table[NIntegrate[Abs[sol[x, y, t]]^2, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}], {t,
   0, 10, 2}]


We can solve this problem using FEM and implicit step as follows
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

boundary = 15; xl = yl = -boundary; xr = yr = boundary; mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{xl, yl}, {xr, yr}], MaxCellMeasure -> .1]

finalt = 10; dt = 1/10;
von[x_, y_] := -2  (Cos[\[Pi]/5  x]^2 + Cos[\[Pi]/5  y]^2);
svalue = 0;
seedwave[x_, y_, 
   t_] := (x^2 + y^2)^(svalue/2)  Exp[
    I*svalue   ArcTan[x, y] - 0.07  (x^2 + y^2)];
pnumber = 
 NIntegrate[Abs[seedwave[x, y, 0]]^2, 
  Element[{x, y}, mesh]](*particle number check*)
Psi[0][x_, y_] := seedwave[x, y, 0]; k[0] = 1;

Do[Psi[i] = 
   Quiet@NDSolveValue[{(\[Psi][x, y] - k[i - 1]  Psi[i - 1][x, y])/
         dt - 0.5   Laplacian[\[Psi][x, y], {x, y}] + 
        Abs[k[i - 1] Psi[i - 1][x, y]]^2   \[Psi][x, y]   Log[
          Abs[k[i - 1] Psi[i - 1][x, y]]^2] + 
        von[x, y]  \[Psi][x, y] == 0, 
      PeriodicBoundaryCondition[\[Psi][x, y], x == xl, 
       TranslationTransform[{xr - xl, 0}]], 
      PeriodicBoundaryCondition[\[Psi][x, y], y == yl, 
       TranslationTransform[{0, yr - yl}]]}, \[Psi], 
     Element[{x, y}, mesh]]; 
  num[i] = NIntegrate[Abs[Psi[i][x, y]]^2, Element[{x, y}, mesh]]; 
  k[i] = Sqrt[pnumber/num[i]], {i, 1, finalt/dt}] // AbsoluteTiming

It takes about 317s on my very slow Silver Pentium. Visualization
{Table[DensityPlot[Abs[k[i] Psi[i][x, y]]^2, {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", i*dt}], 
   ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotPoints -> 100, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic], {i, 20, 100, 20}], 
 Plot[{Abs[k[20] Psi[20][x, 0]]^2, von[x, 0]}, {x, xl, xr}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"sol", "pot"}]} 


Please, note, that scaling is not same as in the paper. But results look same.

Thanks @AlexTrounev. In this program the particle no. does not remain constant. I guess that is the reason scaling came different. how can I get the time dynamics and keep particle no. cons.?

I got a very short MATLAB program for this in the appendix of https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-9590.2008.00398.x using FFT. Can that be implemented in MATHEMATICA?

@ArghaDebnath Actually particles number defined as $k[i]^2\int |\psi|^2dxdy=pnumber$, therefore it does remain constant. Probably we should plot  $|k[i]\psi|^2$, then scaling could be same as in the paper. :)

Thanks for the clarification @AlexTrounev.

@ArghaDebnath You are welcome!
