Solving Non conservative GPE For Phase Portrait
I am trying to solve Eq.(3) from (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378437113002161 or https://sci-hub.se/https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physa.2013.03.013 ).
$$
i\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}=(-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{|\phi|^2}{x^2}-2i\xi\frac{|\phi|^4}{x^4}+i\frac{\Gamma}{2})\phi
$$
$\phi(0)=\phi(\infty)=0$
By switching off the nonconservative terms, a stable solution is obtained. By turning on the nonconservative terms, they saw the dynamical collapse. They have used $\Gamma=0.15;\Delta x=0.004;\Delta t=0.001;l=(0:40);\xi=0.001$. My goal is to obtain the phase plot in fig.(1) between $X(t)=\int_0^\infty{x^2|\phi(x,t)|^2dx}$ vs $\frac{dX(t)}{dt}$.

I solved the equation using imaginary time propagation method without the nonconservative terms.
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
l = 40; finalt = 1; dt = 
 1/1000; \[CapitalGamma] = 0.15; \[Zeta] = 0.001;
g = 1;
pse[x_, t_] := Exp[-((x - 0.3)/0.05)^2];
pnumber = NIntegrate[Abs[pse[x, 0]]^2, {x, 0, l}]
pot[x_] := x^2/4;
Psi[0][x_] := pse[x, 0];
k[0] = 1;
Do[Psi[i] = 
   Quiet@NDSolveValue[{(\[Psi][x] - k[i - 1] Psi[i - 1][x])/dt == 
       Laplacian[\[Psi][x], {x}] + 
        g Abs[k[i - 1] Psi[i - 1][x]]^2   \[Psi][x]/x^2 - 
        pot[x] \[Psi][x],
      DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x] == 0, True]}, \[Psi], {x, 0, l}, 
     Method -> {"FiniteElement", InterpolationOrder -> {\[Psi] -> 2}, 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}];
  num[i] = NIntegrate[Abs[Psi[i][x]]^2, {x, 0, l}];
  k[i] = Sqrt[pnumber/num[i]], {i, 1, finalt/dt}] // AbsoluteTiming

The solution
Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[Abs[k[1000] Psi[1000][x]]^2, {i, 100, 200, 20}]], {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> All]


Then using the solution and switching on the nonconservative terms The dynamics can be seen in Real time
Psi1[0][x_] := Abs[k[1000] Psi[1000][x]]; 
Do[Psi1[i] = 
    Quiet@NDSolveValue[{I (\[Phi][x] - Psi1[i - 1][x])/
          dt == -Laplacian[\[Phi][x], {x}] - 
         g  Abs[Psi1[i - 1][x]]^2    \[Phi][x]/x^2 + 
         pot[x] \[Phi][x] - 
         2 I  \[Zeta]  Abs[Psi1[i - 1][x]]^4 \[Phi][x]/x^4 + 
         I  \[CapitalGamma]  \[Phi][x]/2,
       DirichletCondition[\[Phi][x] == 0, True]}, \[Phi], {x, 0, l}, 
      Method -> {"FiniteElement", InterpolationOrder -> {\[Phi] -> 2},
         "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}];, {i, 1, 
   1000}] // AbsoluteTiming

The dynamics
data = Flatten[
  Evaluate@Table[{i, x, Abs[Psi1[i][x]]^2}, {i, 1, 2000}, {x, 0, 40}],
   1]; ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", 
 FrameLabel -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]


The calculation for phase plot
Needs["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];
gg = GaussianQuadratureWeights[1000, 0, 40];
point = gg[[All, 1]];
weight = gg[[All, 2]];
rms = Table[{t, 
    Sqrt[weight . 
      Table[Evaluate[x^2 Abs[Psi1[t][x]]^2], {x, point}]]}, {t, 0, 
    1000}];
x\[Tau] = Interpolation[rms, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
dx\[Tau][t_] = D[x\[Tau][t], {t, 1}];

Variation of $X(t)$ and $\frac{dX}{dt}$ with $t$
Plot[{x\[Tau][t], dx\[Tau][t]}, {t, 0, 2000}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]


The phase plot
 ParametricPlot[{x\[Tau][t], dx\[Tau][t]}, {t, 0, 2000}, 
             PlotRange -> All]


There is no question to answer here.

@AlexTrounev I would like to obtain the phase plot attached above and know the process of obtaining the Lyapunov exponent I am not getting. Is my method of obtaining the solution without the nonconservative terms and seeing the dynamics switching on them correct? It is kind of the reverse of quench dynamics.

Can you upload the picture you got?

@AlexTrounev I could not upload the parametric phase plot as it's not at all giving anything as $dX/dt$ is coming very small which I uploaded here also the dynamics I am getting.


Seems that you're using the method here for discretization in $t$ direction, but as pointed out therein, your original attempt fails probably because you don't code the equation correctly, you probably need to re-visit this part. 2. How is the initial condition decided? I've checked the paper and the cited papers, but this doesn't seem to be explicitly mentioned.


@xzczd Thank you for your comments. 1. If you point out which one is not working. Imaginary case or the real time case. 2. I guess they decided the initial conditions to avoid the singularity at $x=0$.

I mean everything built on Alex's answer for your previous question. If I understand the solution correctly, Alex "fixes" the code by introducing a normalization on every time step to force conservation, but as pointed out in the comment, the root of the problem is, the PDE itself is wrong.

@xzczd While obtaining the ground state I included the normalization. But in the dynamics as those non-conservative terms cause particle loss for some time and then reach a steady state. That's why I did not include the normalization.

@xzczd Fixing the particle conservation is indeed based on Alex's code. Is there any other process to ensure particle conservation in my previous or in this case.

I don't think we need any extra step to ensure convservation as long as the PDE is correct. Just solve the correct PDE and check, you'll see the conservation is good enough.

@xzczd I took your suggestion and ran https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/306360/solution-of-2d-logarithmic-pde-in-periodic-potential-in-imaginary-time-propagati/306408#306408 again. The particle number remains not exactly but close to the original input. But the solution I am getting changes with time. I ran upto $t=1000$. Each time $t$ gives different profile, confusing me which solution to declare the final one. Not to mention did not give the desired paper's solution.

@xzczd actually $t$ is replaced by $-it$ in PDE for imaginary time propagation and observing the ground state. While for time evolution which is usually done in Real time method where no change in PDE is required.

Oh I didn't notice the imaginary time propagation method isn't an ODE solving method in usual sense. (Well, I'd argue that you should have explained this a bit more in that question. ) Still, I think my comments above are partly valid: the linked paper in this question mentions the equation is solved with semi-implicit CN algorithm, which is a usual ODE solver. So I don't think imaginary time propagation method should be used here.

@ArghaDebnath I don't understand model they used to simulate chaos. From the data they present in the Figure 1, it follows that the number of particles is not conserved and can increase or decrease. While from the model itself this does not follow. For any initial data, the number of particles decreases in this model.

@AlexTrounev Thats right. The particle number is not conserved in the dynamics. It is usually decreasing, then after some time it should reach a constant value because of two counter opposite imaginary terms $\zeta$ and $\Gamma$.

@ArghaDebnath If the number of particles riches the constant, then how the chaos could be in this system? We only can suppose that the number of particles is a constant while   $\Delta x^2$ changes chaotically. Is it correct? See my answer :)

From the data present in the paper in Figure 1, it follows that the number of particles is not conserved and can increase or decrease. While from the model itself this does not follow. For any initial data, the number of particles decreases in this model. On the other hand, the model with particles number stabilizations shows chaotic behaver
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
l = 40; finalt = 30; dt = 
 1/100; \[CapitalGamma] = 0.15; \[Zeta] = 0.001;
g = 1;
pse[x_, t_] := 7 x^2  Exp[-((x - 1))^2];
pnumber = NIntegrate[Abs[pse[x, 0]]^2, {x, 0, l}];
pot[x_] := x^2/4;
Psi1[0][x_] := pse[x, 0];
k[0] = 1;

Do[Psi1[i] = 
   Quiet@NDSolveValue[{I  (\[Phi][x] - k[i - 1] Psi1[i - 1][x])/
         dt == -Laplacian[\[Phi][x], {x}] - 
        g   Abs[k[i - 1] Psi1[i - 1][x]]^2     \[Phi][x]/x^2 + 
        pot[x] \[Phi][x] - 
        2  I   \[Zeta]   Abs[k[i - 1] Psi1[i - 1][x]]^4  \[Phi][x]/
          x^4 + I  \[CapitalGamma]  \[Phi][x]/2, 
      DirichletCondition[\[Phi][x] == 0, True]}, \[Phi], {x, 0, l}, 
     Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1}}]; 
  numb[i] = 
   NIntegrate[Abs[Psi1[i][x]]^2, {x, 0, l}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 4, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"];
  k[i] = Sqrt[pnumber/numb[i]];, {i, 1, 3000}] // AbsoluteTiming

X = Sqrt@
   Table[NIntegrate[x^2 Abs[Psi1[i][x]]^2, {x, 0, l}, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 4, 
     Method -> "LocalAdaptive"], {i, 3000}];

dX = Differences[X]/dt;

ListPlot[Transpose[{Drop[X, 1], dX}], PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue, Background -> Black, Frame -> True]


Update 1. Note that for pse[x_, t_] := .544915 x^2 Exp[-((x - 1))^2] we have pnumber=1, and the corresponding motion looks very regular

But even for pnumber=3 we have chaotic patterns


Could you give me some insights on how their phase plot can be exactly reproduced.@AlexTrounev

Thanks for the answare@AlexTrounev. Can I take the obtained solution from imaginary time method without the non-conservative terms and use it as initial solution for real time propagation with non-conservative terms as I posted above? Is there any another process of obtaining Lyapunov exponent other than ( Eq.[7] fig[2]) from the paper.

In this paper @AlexTrounev https://sci-hub.se/https://doi.org/10.1016/j.chaos.2021.111193 they saw the same dynamics. Do you think to generate fig 1 I need to include particle stabilizer k[I]
or without it will suffice


For my opinion data in Figure 1 cannot be reproduced with implicit step used in your code and above. 2. We don't need preprocessing to get chaotic behaver. Hence, your code with imaginary time is useless. Nevertheless, we need some initial data to reproduce Figure 1. But we don't know how function $\Phi (x,0)$ used in the paper looks like.  It is clear that pnumber>>1, and in our example we take pnumber=165. But it is unclear what pnumber they took to get data in Figure 1.


Thanks, @AlexTrounev for clarification.

@ArghaDebnath Please, pay attention that for pse[x_, t_] := .544915 x^2 Exp[-((x - 1))^2] we have pnumber=1, and the corresponding motion looks very regular - see Update 1.

Thanks, @AlexTrounev For the updates. I would like to have your attention on fig 1(b) of   https://sci-hub.se/https://doi.org/10.1016/j.chaos.2021.111193. They simulate the same equation. They started with $N=20$, with time they see loss of particles and reaches $N=1$ and stabilizes.

@ArghaDebnath Please note, they supposed only one scenario for a dissipative BEC that leads to the particles number decreasing.  But another scenario is that number of particles saved, while position of particles cloud moving chaotically what we see in Figure 1.
